# Where does User in MVC controller come from?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity, membership-provider

I am working on a website that has multiple applications, one of them uses asp.net membership.

In another application I want to get the name of the current user, so I added the following to the web.config so I can get 'User.Identity.Name', note that both apps using same applicationName.

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="CustomProvider" type="myNamespace.CustomProvider" applicationName="/appname"  />
    </providers>
  </membership>

  <machineKey validationKey="vv" decryptionKey="dd" validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto" />
```

What should I do to be able to get the current user identity in the second app?

**Update**:

the structure in the website as following:

[image]

the estore app is adding the forms cookie

I added same machine element in both config (estor config and bol config)

same authentication element:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/account/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10080" requireSSL="true" />
  </authentication>
```

Update 2:

I tried to set the domain although it is not needed because all apps in the same domain but still not working, this is a snapshot for cookies with domain has been set:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info about the CustomProvider? Is it reading from a SQL table like the standard SqlMembershipProvider ?

Comment: Martino Bordin .. Yes it is reading from sql table

Comment: So if you configure the second app with the same provider it should just works.

Comment: @MartinoBordin: it won't work so easy. There is even no guarantee that the forms/identity cookie is shared between the two apps and this alone is not easy (the cookie has to be issued to a top level domain, common to both apps).

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand what @Rana was asking for then. What you are looking for is to get a single sign on. Take a look to this sample: http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: @MartinoBordin I tried single sign on 'see the update' but still not working, I don't know what is wrong in the configuration

Comment: @Rana I see that <machineKey validationKey="vv" decryptionKey="dd" validation="xx" /> contains invalid data (should be similar to the link, example:  validation="HMACSHA256" decryption="AES")..can you update that?

Comment: @Rana: are you sure your forms cookie is issued for a higher level domain so that it really hits **both** applications? Cookies are not shared by default and there doesn't seem to be any sign of domain in your `forms` configuration.

Comment: thanks all, found the problem, the <system.web> section in bol config file was surrounded by   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">, once I removed it, it worked immediately.